# AST traversal functions

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, traversal

I have reading up about lex, yacc and generating ASTs. I have two questions that I'm not able to find a solution for:

1) For parsing and evaluating

```
a = 5;
b = a + 1;
a = 3;
d = a - 2;
```

Given that all 4 statements are evaluations and occupy the same level(?) in the tree, how does the AST capture (or should capture) the program order (so that b is evaluated as 5+1 and not 3+1)?

2) Suppose i have an ast (simplified) as follows:

```
root -> child1 -> grandchild1, grandchild2 
     -> child2 -> grandchild3, grandchild5, grandchild4
                      -> grandgrandchild123 etc
```

if i want to customize printing out the AST based on some input parameters where i print root followed by child1 and child2 or child23 and then all its children, what would be the best way do so? I'm thinking of a simple way where i have a getchild1type(pointer to ast), getchild3type(pointer to ast) etc methods and then iterate over the entire ast in each of these methods as required by the input parameters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) AST are generally ordered trees. Evaluation order is encoded in the order of child nodes. 2) Please clarify your question, no idea what you are asking; and try to stick to a concrete example (such as your code above) rather than the vague "root", "child1" pseudodata.

Answer (score 3):

So the program order should be implicit in the syntax tree.  The tree that should be produced from your example should be something like:

```
       enter
        | 
       seq
        / \ 
       /   \
    assign  \
     / \     seq
    a   5   /   \   
          assign   ...
           /  \
          b    + 
              / \
             a   1
```

You could imagine building an interpreter for your language, which traverses the tree in a left to right depth-first order.  In this case, the `a = 5` statement would get evaluated first and put into some environment that then gets threaded through the rest of the tree.  This way when we eventually get to the `b = a + 1` node, when we look up `a` in the environment, we will get back the result `5`.

### Edit 1

Let's say you represent variables as a string and that all of your values are integers (obviously oversimplified), then you could imagine writing an interpreter to the following effect:

```
int interpretExpr(AST * prog, std::map<string,int>env){
   if(prog is a "variable" node){
      return map.lookup(prog);
   }
   if(prog is a "plus" node){
      return interpretExpr(prog->left, map) + interpretExpr(prog->right, map);
   }
}

std::map<string,int> interpret(AST * prog, std::map<string,int> env){
   if(prog is an "entry" node){
      return interpret(prog->child);
   }
   if(prog is a "seq" node){
      std::map<string,int> newEnv = interpret(prog->leftChild, env);
      return interpret(prog->rightChild, newEnv);
   }
   if(prog is an "exit" node){
      return env;
   }
}
```

This will take in an `AST` and an environment, which maps `string`s (variables) to `int`s (values).  You can then implement this function in the following way:

This is pretty rough pseudocode, but basically the idea is to recursively interpret statements, threading the environment through the evaluation.

Comment: @slayer:  The key thing to note here is the additional SEQ nodes in the tree which represent the "seq"uential ordering of the statements.   (You might say, "Hey, I don't see any SEQ operator in my source code" ... Sure you do, it is spelled ";"!)

Comment: Thanks, Matt - could you please elaborate on what kind of environment/structure would be best (in your sentence, a = 5 gets evaluated first and put in some `environment'). @Ira: Yes,  i was definitely thinking what/where those SEQ nodes propped up from when I first read Matt's answer